# Easiest way to set up a "proper" VPN on a CentOS server, allowing an Ubuntu or Windows client to connect to it

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, centos

I am using Ubuntu at home. I have a server in the US with CentOS.

With my system administrator days long gone (about 25 years ago), the question is: what's the easiest, least painful way to make a CentOS Linux server act as a full VPN, and then route ALL of my traffic to that US server?

When I look online, I find plenty of guides for Squid (not what I want), more about Socks (again, not what I want since I want ALL traffic to go through the VPN), and difficult guides on how to set a VPN on a server. Are there any turnkey-ish solutions out there? Something I can use with the standard Ubuntu UI (or Windows' UI for VPNs), which allows me to add a VPN?

(If you wondered, in the last 25 years I've been a tech journalist and software engineer, rather than system administrator)

Comment: with which streaming service are you having issues?

Comment: The one that ends with 'flix"!

Comment: “It's not the IP address”—oh, but is most definitely is. The equation can really rather simple: Traffic isn’t coming from a known home ISP range? Block it. Done!

Comment: What... really? I am nearly finished following this  odyssey of a tutorial... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7 Waste of time? The IP will still get blocked?

Comment: Confirmed: waste of time. I tried fetching the home page from the server, and guess what? Denied, 403. Same identical request from my normal machine: granted (well I got a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` but still, didn't get a 403). So it IS the IP address.. damn it.

Comment: (should I delete the question?)

Comment: @Merc - You should improve it. If you cannot improve it so an answer can be submitted, then and only then, should you delete it. Netflix actively blocks VPN services including VPS that host them.

Comment: I deleted the whole spill about Netflix etc. I THINK the question still has merit -- even though the answer won't actually help me in the slightest!)

Comment: Setting up the US CentIS box to route and NAT traffic, then setti g up Wireguard. (OpenVPN is also a good option, but more complex and more resource intensive)

Comment: What about OpenVPN configured as TAP on whatever server the WAN IP is wanted for streaming? _(TAP effectively acts as a router plugged into one of the LAN ports on the existing router)_

Comment: "US CentIS box" <--- did you mean CentOs?

Comment: I am confused. There is a "close" request, and yet this question 1) IS about software 2) Is NOT about hardware shopping recommendation 3) Is NOT about a product, service, or learning material which will become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. I asked a very simple, and very technical, and also very specific, question!

Comment: It's a single close request. Don't worry about that. Either a community moderator would have to agree with that or 4 other community members. Don't sweat a single close vote.